# Rails html5 data-attributes are not passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I have a partial to display users:

```
%table.table
  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td= avatar_tag user, {small:true, rounded:true}
        %td
          = username user
          .online-tag
            = user.online?
        %td= email_tag user.email
        %td= user.country
        %td
          - unless user == current_user
            #lll
              = link_to '#messageFormModal', data: {toggle: :modal, receiver: '2'}, class: 'btn btn-primary'  do
                %i.icon--envelope
                = t('globals.send_message')

      = render 'messages/message_form'
```

and I have a modal which will be displayed after user clicks on the `link_to 'messgeFormModal'`.

My javascript file must capture attributes passed into modal and alert them but I only see `'undentified'` :

```
$(document).on("click", "#lll", function () {
    var receiverId = $(this).data('receiver');
    alert(receiverId);
});
```

Is my syntax right? or maybe I pass params to it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is

```
$(document).on("click", "#lll a", function () {
    var receiverId = $(this).data('receiver');
    alert(receiverId);
});
```